# Can you use operators to define the size of an array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

Right now I'm trying to write a program, and one part of the it involves expanding an existing array by copying values from a previous array into an array with a larger size.

The way I'm doing this by using an int variable which is defined in a previous point int the program by user input.

```
int[x] array;

int[x + 1] array2;
```

Will this work, or do I have to initialize a separate int variable with value of x + 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
int array[x];
int array2[x+1];
```

C 1999 and later supports this (with the value of `x` determined at run time), although it is optional in C 2011. Some compilers (of questionable quality) do not support it.

The space available for objects of this sort is typically limited to one to eight mebibytes or so, and that space must also serve for other program needs, so it should be used only for small arrays.